# Git - git remote

Tags: git, github

In `Git`, if we have the following command:

```
$ git remote add myapp git@github.com:xyz/myapp.git
```

What does this command mean? And, does it differ if we replace `myapp` with `origin`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Git remote means you link a git URI to a name, to a label.

If `git@github.com:xyz/myapp.git` is the URI you'll want to push to, then if you write

`git remote add myapp git@github.com:xyz/myapp.git`

instead of

`git remote add origin git@github.com:xyz/myapp.git`
 you'll have to modify the push command too, like this:

`git push myapp`

This is not always true, you can set up a remote for some other repo because you want to have fast access to it.

For example if you'll get a lot of pull request from the same user/repo you will want to add a remote for that repo so you can inspect changes made to it(the repo linked by the remote).

Please read:

http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html -> if you read this you'll understand git remotes completely

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Answer (score 0):

Well the above command essentially is to tell git where the remote repository you intend to check on .

If you peek into the config file under .git you will see something like ::

```
[remote "origin"]
url = git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git
```

That would be [remote "myapp"] in your case .

EDITED ::

You won't modify the default push "path", you'll just compress these commands: git remote rm origin and git remote add myapp ,

Comment: Wrong: you won't modify the default push "path", you'll just compress these commands: `git remote rm origin` and `git remote add myapp <URI>`, so it's like you'll delete the remote 'origin' and create 'myapp'